# Finding a set of point satisfying complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The question says to "find geometrically the set of points $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$ such that $$x+2yi=|x+yi|$$

I'm kinda lost on this one, I've tried solving the equation directly but I don't even know what to do with that. Here's what I have right now:

$$x+2yi = |x+yi|$$
$$x+2yi = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$x^2+4yxi-4y^2=x^2+y^2$$
$$4yxi=5y^2$$
$$y=0 \lor -5y+4xi=0$$
$$y=0 \lor y=\frac{4xi}5$$

I don't know what to do with this... I'm reading Ahlfors' Complex Analysis but this type of exercise seems kind of weird to me.

Comment: Looking at your very first line, what can you say about the right hand side's imaginary part?

Comment: It's true for every $x\geq 0$ and $y=0$. And these describe the whole set of solutions.

Comment: $$(x,y)=(t,0); t\in [0,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the right hand side is strictly real (and non-negative), we must have $y=0$, as $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. So, the equation becomes $x = |x|$, and the solution set is $\{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \geq 0\}$.

Geometrically, this is the non-negative real axis, or the halfline $[0, \infty) \times \{0\}$.

Comment: why can't $x$ be 0 ?

Comment: my mistake, fixed.

Comment: I completely forgot that $y \in \Bbb R$, that makes everything clearer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

L.H.S is complex in nature where as R.H.S is Real. Thus $y$ has to be zero. So your solution is all Real for $x$ and $y$ is zero.

Now if $x$ and $y$ were complex you had to make sure the complex parts were canceled in L.H.S and solve for the rest